# C: How to add a character to another character / set of characters?

Tags: c

Let's say I have a char with a value of 42 (*). I need to print this character in n lines, with n defined by the user. However, for each line shift, another * must be printed. If the user inputs "6", then the result would be like that:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

I was thinking of making the program repeat the print and jump a line n times, adding another * to the char at the end of each loop. Is there any command that would turn * into ** and then into *** and so on?

Comment: Post some code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use nested for loop for this purpose...

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)     //n is your user value
{
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
         {
          printf("%c",your_char);     //print char here
         }
    printf("\n");                    //for going to next line
}
```

the top `for` loop will handle the row while the inner `for` loop will deal with the column...

Comment: Change the first for loop to `for(i=1;i<=n;i++);` otherwise the last line won't be printed.

Comment: No need to use `printf`. I like `putchar` as it will be faster :)

Comment: @Phoen1xUK But your version makes a lot more logical sense.

Comment: @Bechir Why is putchar faster?

Comment: In @Phoen1xUK's version, `i` is the number of chars to print and the inner loop is a standard C for loop that prints `i` chars. In your version, `i` is *one less* than the number of chars to print and the inner loop prints *one more* char than `i`. They both do the same thing, but the first one is more logical and easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve it by putting i and j integers and using while. I also had to reset j to 0 before the newline, otherwise it would print only one * each line.

Comment: @Armin Have you thought about it? `printf` has to parse the format string, handle all the qualifiers (which are absent in this case), switch on the format char (c), and then get around to calling `putchar` on the single char. Oh, and then it goes back and looks at the format string to see if there's anything else to do. Also, `printf` calls `vprintf` so there's some more overhead. Meanwhile, `putchar` is just a macro that decrements a count, tests it for 0, and then puts a `char` in a buffer.

Comment: @JimBalter Wasn't sure if printf uses putc for printing. I checked the source and it does.

Comment: @Armin It wouldn't matter whether it does ... it still is necessarily much much slower.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to do any string manipulation.  For each line, if the line number is `i`, just print out a single asterisk (with `putchar()` or the like) `i` times, followed by a newline.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 void print_n_chars(char c, size_t count)
 {
     char *buffer;
     size_t i;

     buffer = malloc(count + 1);
     memset(buffer, 0, count + 1);

     for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
         buffer[i] = c;

         printf("%s\n", buffer);
     }

     free(buffer);
 }
```

This algorithm has `O(n)` performance, which is better then `O(n^2/2)` with two loops.

Edit: fixed name typo, added performance comments

Comment: You've got two different names for the pointer: buf and buffer.

Comment: @Armin Depends. Several printfs can be considerably slower than my option. The algorithm in your example has performance of `O(n^2/2)`. My alternative has `O(n)` performance